# How do I recover/use Powerpoint speaker notes after import to LibreOffice Impress?

Tags: libreoffice

I have several MS Office Powerpoints that I would like to view in LibreOffice Impress.  The slides import without any problems, but the speaker notes appear to be missing.  How do I recover/access the notes and view them in Impress?

Comment: do you have the latest libreoffice?

Comment: I had 3.5.3 but I just installed 3.5.4.2 and have the same problem.

Comment: Which format are you using? Bear in mind that the Office Open XML formats (`pptx`, `docx`, etc) are not as well supported as the "traditional" binary formats (`ppt`, `doc`, etc, usually presented as "Microsoft Office 97/2000/XP").

Comment: The format was the issue. The older formats seem to work.  I just discovered that the notes from some of the new format files are there, but the formatting is way off.  This might be easy to fix but I think saving in the old format first is the trick.  Sorry.  I thought I had tried this before and it didn't work but I guess not.

Comment: Is it really a linux unix matter ? libre office is running on any OS, I think this topic should be move to Super user non ?